# how to share constants between Java and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have in my java classes static variables CONSTANT_1, CONSTANT_2...
What is the best way to share these constants with my javascript functions or if there is a JQuery plugin for this.

Till now the only solution I can think of, is an ajax call in the beginning, to send these static variables to the client.

Thanks

Comment: Addressing the same issue we came up with the same solution.

Comment: Why only AJAX call ? You can send data from server to client in HTML response and use them in JS!

Comment: Consider code generation from a definition file of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know whether this the best way or not, but it works.

```
var constant1=<%=class.CONSTANT_1%>;
```

Comment: He didn't say he was using JSP. In fact, he wasn't saying what he was using at all, so any answer is kind of pointless.

Comment: He mentioned as Ajax so we can consider the above answer :-)

Comment: Actually i am using JSP, but i avoid mixing jsp with js in the same file.

Comment: Thank you also. I agree this method is convenient for maintance & clean code.BTW, we should use var constant1='<%=class.CONSTANT_1%>'; for String constant.

Answer (score 1):

you can set this static variable in a hidden field, then you can access it by javascript using this hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" value="<your static variable>" id="staticVariable" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStaticField(){
        return document.getElementById("staticVariable").value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before. what i did is simply i declared `hidden` input field that i can access on the server side and set it's value with whatever i want.

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hiddenInput" />
```

then using the programming language(I use c#):

```
hiddenInput.Value = ValueOnServerSide;
```

Then using jQuery i get the value of this input on the client side.

```
$("[id$='hiddenInput']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Technology called `'DWR' (directwebremoting)`.

By using this we can access Java classes directly in Javascript.

Try this, it may helpful to you.

Refference Links:

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/scripting-dwr.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX calls to get the value of the constants if you dont want to keep reloading the page.
If you are fine with the value only updating on refresh you can do what Sainath has told, this way you are not making unnecessary AJAX calls:

```
var constant1=<%=class.CONSTANT_1%>;
```